# Using C# to automate functions and movement between two different browser applications?

Tags: automation, webbrowser-control

I'm a newb. So forgive me if I'm vague or not specific enough to be helpful, please let me know so I can clarify.

I use 2 different applications for work and would be interested in a little tool to automate some of the functions. 
1. IP Based phone system we use.
    We have to copy and paste numbers from one web browser (always located in same field, text area)
    And select several buttons
2. Mortgage Application terminal run through web browser.

I would like to click a button, have it copy text (ie the number) from the field in the mortgage servicing application, then paste that info to the textbox on the other browser that is our phone system and select from several different radio buttons, hit the next button and then it will dial.

We have SUCH a slow system, with too many clicks to i'm hoping this would be feasible without super advanced programming knowledge. Tips?

One script that I've reviewed from VBScript shows excerpts... (i've done mild VBA, but not a Vbscript master! )

Is this possible, or am I stuck to clicking everything individually?

```
Dim at99999Tool, atlDirectorObject   
Dim strErrMsg   
Dim strScreenName   
Dim strLoanNumber   

Const S_OK=0  
Const DELAY=60  
Const QUOTES = """"   

subGetSession   
strScreenName=Wscript.Arguments(0)   
strLoanNumber=Wscript.Arguments(1)   
subGoToScreen strScreenName, "********", strLoanNumber   

subTerminateScript 3, ""   

more functions etc...   

Sub subGetSession()   

  Set atlDirectorObject = CreateObject("atlDirectorObject.atlDirector")   
  If atlDirectorObject.CreateTool("9999", 1, True, True, 0, atl3299Tool, strErrMsg) <> S_OK Then   
     subTerminateScript 2, strErrMsg   
  End If   
End Sub
```